# Getting data from flask request is slow

Tags: python, flask, request

I have a device sending POSTs to my server. In python, I grab the posted data using either:

```
request.data
request.get_data
request.get_json
```

But the times I can getting for these simple data gets varies. I test with something like this:

```
start = time.time()
resp = request.data
return str(time.time() - start)
```

From some end nodes, I see times of sub 1ms, and some, I see over 100ms, for the same amount of data.  Since the request object is already created, and I assume the data is already received, what contributes to this variance in speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I assume the data is already received

Don't assume :)

Flask uses the request class from Werkzeug [which calls `get_data`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L468). `get_data` either already has the data cached, or [reads the stream](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/778f482d1ac0c9e8e98f774d2595e9074e6984d7/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L514).

There's even a warning in the docstring:

> Usually it's a bad idea to call this method without checking the
>           content length first as a client could send dozens of megabytes or more
>           to cause memory problems on the server.

If you want to be safe from blocking your server on a slow request, you should put some reverse proxy in front of it (nginx?) which can handle the input more efficiently and hand over a full request to the server when ready.

Comment: Thanks @viraptor, I am seeing ~100ms of delay on ~30 bytes of data, which I thought would be too slow for just reading a stream, but I'll try to verify that this is the root cause.